# How to include bash scripts in a package?

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools

I need to include several bash scripts in the R package I'm writing. I'd love to distribute them together with the package, so when a user installs the package via `devtools::install_github(...)` he/she gets the scripts as well.

I know it is possible, but I don't know how. Including the files in the `scripts` subdirectory doesn't seem to suffice. I need a means to tell R (or RStudio) to include them.

I use RStudio for development, so I would appreciate a solution that integrates with the "Build package" functionality that RStudio provides.

Comment: _"I know it is possible"_, any references for that?

Comment: It might be good to clarify if you want to submit to CRAN at some point.

Comment: @Axeman I've poked around local library of various R packages, and some of them contain foreign files. e.g. `acepack` contains a Word document in the root folder.

Comment: @Axeman Actually I don't know if I want to submit the package to CRAN. Github works fine for what I need. Of course I'd be glad to maintain potential CRAN-compatibility, if it doesn't sacrifice usability.

Comment: @Axeman Another example is `doParallel` that contains bash script in the `unitTests` subfolder.

Comment: See the bottom of [this page](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/inst.html#inst-other-langs).

Answer (score 7):

Simply add whatever you want to the `inst/xxx` folder in your package.

The folder will get installed as `xxx` when you compile/publish the package as a library.

You access the files via `system.file()`, e.g.

```
system.file('scripts/peak_mem.sh', package='clustertools')
```

See more details on the [R packages by Hadley Wickham](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/inst.html#inst-other-langs)

Thank you @Axeman!